# How can I make IntelliJ insert a copyright header by default in each new project?

Tags: intellij-idea, copyright-display

Why does Intellij Idea make it so difficult to have a simple message that is added at the top of each file. ie.
/**
* Created on date
* Copyright by developer
*/
Maybe I'm reading it wrong but creating a profile, adding a scope and having to manually insert in each individual project seems like a lot of work and leaves a hole if one is distracted and forgets. At the end of the project do you need to back and manually insert in every file?

Comment: I have not used this feature. I'm sure there is a way to insert the copyright automatically in any new file.

Comment: Note that a question that's written more like a rant or complaint than a *question* as such is likely to be poorly received. It's better to spend your time (and our time as readers!) being specific about what you've tried than expressing exasperation.

Comment: ... I've at least edited the title to be more explicit about what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copyright settings for new projects should be saved if you define them in *File | New Projects Settings | Preferences for new project*. But unfortunately they aren't, please follow the bug already created for it at YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-207505